# DBeaver(3.8.5) unable to connect to Cassandra 2.1.2 (NoHostAvailableException)

Tags: cassandra, dbeaver

My DBeaver Enterprise Edition is unable to connect to a remote Cassandra store (2.1.2) on a Unix machine in the same network.It's throwing a **NoHostAvailableException- All host(s) tried for query failed.** The firewall is down on the Unix machine,the tcp port in cassandra.yaml is 9042 & I am using the same port in the DBeaver Connection configuration. I am also using SSH tunnel in the configuration to connect to the Unix machine.

I could use some help on fixing this problem.

Comment: Can you telnet to the host and port? If yes the problem is likely in the configuration of your tool. If not, the problem is likely on the Cassandra side. If that is the case, what have you set for `rpc_address` or `rpc_interface`?

Comment: no I am unable to telnet to the host & port...I am not able to telnet to the host even on default port 23 but I am able to do an SSH using putty

Comment: Probably there is no telnet server running? But if you cannot telnet to the C* port, then you have a server config issue. What is set as rpc_address or rpc_interface?

Comment: Out of curiosity: I just downloaded DBeaver to give it a spin and could not see a Cassandra connection type when starting it up. What connection type are you trying?

Comment: Cassandra driver is available on Enterprise edition(its free) not on Community edition...btw **rpc_address: 127.0.0.1  rpc_interface is commented & rpc_port is 9160**

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is your loopback address. You cannot reach a service bound to this IP from any other host than the local host. If you want to reach C* from another host you need to set rpc_address to the IP fo your host.

Comment: your suggestion worked like a charm...thank you :)